# Dart, Flutter List onTap to get index of taped item

Tags: list, flutter, dart, indexing

i created a search delegate class and what i want sounds logically simple but i cant wrap my head around it as i am new programming 
i want to get the text or maybe i should say string of the text in the listTile i tap on ,
then pass that text to the showResult of search delegate and view it in a text widget
... here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:schooler/style/const.dart';
//follow steps 1 - 3
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  final List<String> languages = [//3.here is my list
    'dart',
    'Csharp',
    'Java',
    'JavaScript',
    'C++',
    'go ',
    'python',
    'php'
  ];

  final List<String> recentSearch = [
    'go ',
    'python',
    'php',
  ];
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        progress: transitionAnimation,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(),
              Text(languages[0].substring(query.length)),//2.i want to return the gotten index here
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? recentSearch
        : languages.where((element) => element.startsWith(query)).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          showResults(context); //1.when i tap the item on the listTile i want it to get the index of the taped item
        },
        leading: query.isEmpty
            ? Icon(
                Icons.history,
              )
            : Icon(Icons.search),
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            text: suggestionList[index].substring(
              0,
              query.length,
            ),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: kBlackColor,
              fontWeight: kBold,
            ),
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: suggestionList[index].substring(query.length),
                style: TextStyle(color: kGreyColor),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
    );
  }
}
```

[here if i tap on 'go' it should get get the text and pass it to the showResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gZ6N.jpg)

[here is my show result ..but i just hard coded my 'list[0]index in there' i guess what i am trying to say is get the text from the item i taped and show it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6bAf.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First lets fix your itemBuilder in your ListView so it indexes each element and then add that index into your showResults() function call so you have access to it:

```
ListView.builder(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile( // Add index here to pass the index to the builder.
        onTap: () {
          showResults(context, index); // Add the index to function call
        },
```

Just be sure your showResults() function is modified to accept an int index parameter, and while I dont see that function, I am assuming it calls buildResults() at some point which needs to be modified to accept an index:

```
@override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(),
              Text(languages[index].substring(query.length)),// Use the index here to return the desired text
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: please how do you suggest i modify the `showResult()` function to accept `int` ?

Comment: Can you add the code for showResult() to your post so I can see what it does currently?

Comment: i am using the default flutter search class, extend search delegate